# Is there a scripture that refers to the circumambulation (kora/parikrama) around Mt Kailash?

Tags: scripture, shiva, kailasa

Hi I am researching the religious reason behind the walk around Mt Kailash and am looking for some hindu text that refers to the salvation they receive from taking part in the walk.

Comment: what does kora mean? I [searched](https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=TT#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hi&text=kora) but couldn't understand it's context here...

Comment: @YDS kora refers to the circumambulation (Parikrama) of Mt. kailasa...